# Torsion subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices

Let $G$ be subgroup of $SL(n,Z)$ such that for any $g\in G$ there exists integer $m\geq1$ $g^m=1$.

Show that there exists $N\geq1$ such that for any $g\in G$ , $g^N=1$

I know $m$-th root of unity is the eigenvalue of elements, any element is diagonalizable matrix over complex number but I don't know how to use facts?
any suggestion?

Comment: If $g$ was diagonal, what would $g^m$ look like?

Comment: @steve both g and $g^m$ are diagonal

Comment: OK... a better question: what can you say about the minimal polynomial of such a $g$?

Comment: $x^m-1$ is divide by minimal polynomial

Comment: The irreducible factors of $x^m-1$ are the cyclotomic polynomials $\Phi_d(x)$ with $d|m$. So the minimal polynomial of $g$ is a product of some of these $\Phi_d(x)$. If $g$ has order $m$, then the least common multiple of the $d$ arising in this factorization must be $m$. That should be enough to enable you to bound $m$ as a function of the degree of the minimal polynomial of $g$.

Comment: @DerekHolt why should be enough to enable you to bound m as a function of the degree of the minimal polynomial of g?

Comment: For each $p^d$ in the factorization of $m$ into prime powers, one of the factors of the minimal polynomial of $g$ must have degree a multiple of (and hence at least) $\phi(p^d) = (p-1)p^{d-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've got it (but check it, it won't be the first time I produce a wrong proof!).

- **First step:** Let $\mathcal P$ the set of monic polynomials of degree $n$, with coefficients lying in $\mathbb Z$, and the roots in the unit circle of the complex plane. Then $\mathcal P$ is finite. Indeed, fix $0\leq k\leq n-1$ and for $P\in\mathcal P$, $P=X^n+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_jX^j$, with roots $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, we have 
  $$a_j=(-1)^j\sum_{J\subset\{1,\ldots,n\},|J|=j}\prod_{k\in J}\lambda_k$$
  so $|a_j|\leq \binom nj$ and since $a_j$ is an integer it can take only a finite number of values.
- **Second step:** For each $g\in G$, the characteristic polynomial of $g$, $p_g$, is an element of $\mathcal P$, so the set of all eigenvalues of the elements of $G$ is finite, and is contained in $\bigcup_{n\geq 1}\mathbb U_n$, where $\mathbb U_n$ is the sets of $n$-th roots of unity. So in fact the eigenvalues are contained in $\bigcup_{j=1}^{n_0}\mathbb U_{k_j}$, where $k_j$ are natural numbers $\geq 1$. Taking $N:=\operatorname{ppcm}(k_j,1\leq j\leq n_0)$, we get the wanted result.

Comment: @Marc Thanks for editing.

Comment: I understand the first step. I don't think I understand the second step. Just because $\lambda^{N} =1$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda$ (of every $g\in G$), why does it imply that $g^{N} = 1$ for all $g\in G$?

Comment: Because $g$ is diagonalizable in $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic polynomial of $g\in G$ has degree $n$, and thus the minimal polynomial satisfied by $g$ has degree $\le n$ and divides $x^m-1$, i.e. is a cyclotomic polynomial. The degree of $k^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial is $\phi(k)$. Thus, if $g$ satisfies $k^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial then $\phi(k)\le n$. This is a finite set, and the $\operatorname{lcm}$ of this set works.

Answer (score 0):

[Lemma A2](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jYf3V_0qpXgC&lpg=PA152&ots=OnLkXK2esw&dq=A%20Brief%20Guide%20to%20Algebraic%20Number%20Theory&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q&f=false) in the appendix of Swinnerton-Dyer's "Brief guide to Algebraic Number Theory" that might help solving your question. I am really sorry for giving this reference this way. I think this Lemma (or a similar version) has a commonly known name, but I just can not remember it. It states

Let $G$ be a f.g. abelian and torsion free group, and let $H$ be a subgroup. Then there exists a minimal base $x_1, \dots, x_n$ of $G$ and integers $m_1, \dots m_r$, $r≤n$, such that $m_{i+1}$ divides $m_{i}$ and $m_1 x_1, \dots, m_r x_r$ are a bases for $H$.

maybe the condition "abelian" can be withdrawn

Comment: I don't think the group $G$ of the question is abelian.

Comment: yes,I am agree with Marc, it is not abelian

Comment: No, the condition "abelian" cannot be removed from the theorem. For example, the free group of rank $2$ is finitely generated and torsion free. The commutator subgroup, however, is not finitely generated, so you cannot possibly find a basis (free generating set) for $G$ and integers as given to yield a finite generating set, let alone a free generating set, for $H$.